# How can I optimise ext4 for reliability?

Tags: filesystem, ext4

As ext4 was introduced as more reliable than ext3 with block journals, is there any chance to suppose it 100% reliable? What if enabling block journaling on it, which is disabled by default?

As friend's guide to explain my case in more detail:
I have an embedded linux device, after installation keyboard and monitor is detached and it works standalone.

My duty is to make sure it has reliable file-system so with errors there is no way for manual correct faults on device. **I can't force my customer to use a ups with each device to ensure no fault by power-failure.**

What more can ext4 offer me besides block journaling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know i have some trade off enabling features like block journaling, but i am sticked in to reliability and am ready to pay for it

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/244095/how-to-make-ext4-more-reliable , closed for being too ambiguous.

Comment: yes i asked my question there and there were no help just closed! my linux system is an embedded system with no monitor or keyboard attached. so i want it to be more reliable in case of power failure, etc ... i know block journaling is a way but i want to know if there is any more option. i can't offer my customer to have a ups for each device.

Comment: @amin The information about your usecase would be more useful in your question, that's probably why it was closed for being to ambiguous; add more info to your question!

Comment: Question is too vague.  What does "100% reliable" mean?  Assuming that by "block jounrnaling" you mean data=journal, then that is just a giant waste of time.  The FS is inherently reliable; a journal just makes sure you don't have to wait through a lengthy fsck after a crash.

Comment: question is modified now due to your guides, do you have a guide then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You can never suppose something to be 100% reliable.

Journaling file systems minimise data loss in the event of an unexpected outage. [Extents and barriers](http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4#head-25c0a1275a571f7332fa196d4437c38e79f39f63) help even more, but cannot eliminate all associated problems. Personally, I've never experienced data loss because of file system corruption when using journaling file systems.

Also, journaling **is not** disabled by default.

Here's a good overview of ext4 and its improvements: http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4

Comment: +1 for "you can never suppose something to be 100% reliable"

Comment: as [Comparison_of_file_systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) block journaling is off while metadata journaling is on, that's trade off between reliability and speed

Comment: I just had a server reboot in order to find massive data corruption on ext4 where files contain invalid data.  This could not have happened on zfs or btrfs because data has checksums.

Comment: Someone suggest changing the link to the new [ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org), but that wiki doesn't have an overview of ext4, and instead links back to the kernel newbies page. 

Comment: Rejected another edit because the newer "up to date" wiki doesn't have any of the information needed, and actually redirects the reader to the kernelnewbies site.

Answer (score 5):

A new feature added to ext4 and introduced with kernel 3.5 is what is known as 'metadata checksums', which is another feature of ext4 that is supposed to improve the reliability and the integrity of the structure of the file system.

The overall implementation is well explained at [Kernel newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.5#head-e8ea0d70436ea63590eac3dc25a7b417333147f8):

> Modern filesystems such as ZFS and Btrfs have proved that ensuring the integrity of the filesystem using checksums is a valuable feature. Ext4 has added the ability to store checksums of various metadata fields. Every time a metadata field is read, the checksum of the read data is compared with the stored checksums, if they are different it means that the medata is corrupted (note that this feature doesn't cover data, only the internal metadata structures, and it doesn't have "self-healing" capabilities).
>
> Any ext4 filesystem can be upgraded to use checksums using the "tune2fs -O metadata_csum" command, or "mkfs -O metadata_csum" at creation time. Once this feature is enabled in a filesystem, older kernels with no checksum support will only be able to mount it in read-only mode.

Articles such as [this one at kernel.org](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums) discuss further in great technical detail how using metadata checksums can prevent corrupted metadata from damaging the file system structure.

However the article also warns that:

> The metadata checksumming code started going into mainline in Linux 3.5, and as of 3.7-rc1 it is undergoing some user testing. This code is not yet rock solid.

It is not enabled by default in Ubuntu 12.10, and is probably best not to enable it for the moment after the recent issues with the ext4 filesystem, as noted [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIxNDQ).

Answer (score 1):

You could disable delayed allocation under ext4 (nodelalloc), that would make it significantly more likely that you would recover more data if/when you did suffer a power out during a write, but it would come at the cost of more fragmentation of the file system over time.